# JFrame - Is using multiple panels in one JFrame a good practice?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Right now, I'm making some report generator that has only less than 9 pages (or Panels). I was thinking what if I just contain these within one frame. I'll just call and dispose panel Instances whenever I need. This is to contain things like the db Connection into just one `JFrame` and not always calling `.setVisible(true)` and `.setVisible(false)` whenever switching Pages. This is to also when the user clicks the close button on any page, the whole Software closes without the need to call multiple `.dispose()` methods.

I wonder if this will be possible or will it just complicate the whole development process.

Right now I have this within my `MainFrame` Class (Which is the frame class).

```
public MainFrame(){
    setContentPane(new LoginScreen(this));
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Now to my knowledge, the `setContentPane()` can call another `JPanel` to show to the user. But, can you dispose a panel? Because to my knowledge, the `.dispose()` is reserved for the `JFrame`.

Comment: You may me interested in [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is OK to place multiple JPanel objects into one JFrame object. However, you should `add` or `remove` those panels, not `dispose` them.

But, in your situation, the best choice, I think, is [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html). You can do all you need with it. Do not manually `add` and `remove` panels.

There is an official example for [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html.

Comment: It seems that I may be able to use that. I already have two 'jPanel' classes. Can I directly use those for the CardLayout? or do I have do do some slight reprogramming?

Comment: The CardLayout is very easy to use. I have updated my answer with an official example for CardLayout usage. @DarkThunder